# iTextSharp reading files > 1GB

Tags: c#, pdf, c#-4.0, itext

I am trying to read in PDFs stored on a DB from a deflate stream.  It has worked on tens of thousands of files so far, but now I've hit a big one, and it just idles on the new PdfReader line:

```
byte raw = reader.GetSqlBinary(reader.GetOrdinal("doc_data")).Value;
using(Stream stream = new MemoryStream(raw)){
stream.ReadByte();//read I need to do this is another
stream.ReadByte();//SO post, it breaks without it
using(DeflateStream d_Stream = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using(pdfreader=new PdfReader(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(d_Stream),null))//sits here and doesn't do anything
```

Is there something else I should be doing for large files?  Perhaps handling the RandomAccessFileOrArray differently?  It does tell me it's obsolete, but couldn't find a better way to do it with a stream.
Does PDFReader have a max size?  The file I'm reading is just under a GB, but there could be larger files to come as well.

Comment: In old PDF versions, `PdfReader` had a size limit, in new versions (5.3 and higher), you may be limited by the memory available on your machine.

Comment: Also, not only are you trying to load a giant file into memory, you are also loading a giant _compressed_ file into memory. I don't know the internals of `DeflateStream` but you might actually by double your in-memory footprint because of this. You might want to try completely decompressing your bytes first and then binding a native uncompressed `MemoryStream` to `PdfReader`.